# Combine multiple " = " criteria into one statement

Tags: google-sheets

I'm doing a filter and I basically have this

```
filter('Sheet'!B2:B,

('Sheet'!A2:A=1)+
('Sheet'!A2:A=2)+
('Sheet'!A2:A=3)+
('Sheet'!A2:A=4)+
('Sheet'!A2:A=5)

)
```

I'd like to simplify this as follows:

```
filter('Sheet'!B2:B,

'Sheet'!A2:A in (1,2,3,4,5)

)
```

Anyone have any idea if I can do this?

Here's a screenshot of my actual code:

[image: Screenshot here with my actual code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=FILTER('Sheet'!B2:B, not(isna(match('Sheet'!A2:A, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 0))))
```